# How to update document in Mongodb collection with a field value from another collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections 
1) Floorplan_backup.
  The structure of the document looks like :-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5877e18a88db272b578572bd"),
    "floorplans" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Campus Center - Atrium",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(3),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Campus Center - Bridge ",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(4),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Campus Center - Top",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(5),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Performance Dining Hall",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(6),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Main Kitchen",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(7),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Board of Trustees",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(8),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Academic Affairs",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(9),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Admissions",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(10),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Athletics",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(11),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Financial",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(14),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - HR",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(15),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Institutional",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(16),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - IT",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(17),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 

        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Student Success",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(20),
            "cameras" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "OrgChart - Student Life",
            "uuid" : NumberLong(21),
            "cameras" : []
        }
    ],
    "userid" : "user-56cb3c4c0c953470865336",
    "firstviewhost" : undefined
}
```

2) Floorplan . The structure of the document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589025b03422cafc09913363"),
    "userid" : "user-56cb3c4c0c953470865336",
    "firstviewhost" : "dean.vizsafe.com"
}
```

I would like to update the firstviewhost in Floorpla_backup with the value "dean.vizsafe.com" by matching the userid of both the collections.

The javascript code used is :-

```
db.floorplan_backup.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.floorplan.find({ userid: doc1.userid }, { firstviewhost: 1 });
    if (doc2 != null) {
        doc1.firstviewhost = doc2.firstviewhost;
        db.floorplan_backup.save(doc1);
    }
});
```

But is is not giving me the desired resultset . Could you let me know what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find returns you a cursor, instead use findOne.

```
db.floorplan_backup.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.floorplan.findOne({ userid: doc1.userid }, { firstviewhost: 1 });
    if (doc2 != null) {
        doc1.firstviewhost = doc2.firstviewhost;
        db.floorplan_backup.save(doc1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

doc2 is an array. Use findOne to get an object.

```
db.floorplan_backup.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.floorplan.findOne({ userid: doc1.userid }, { firstviewhost: 1 });
    if (doc2 != null) {
        doc1.firstviewhost = doc2.firstviewhost;
        db.floorplan_backup.save(doc1);
    }
});
```